# When to use reflection instead of referencing an assembly

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I created a dll in .NET Framework and use it now in another project. I found 2 ways to use my dll.

1. By referencing the dll in my projects References and creating an instance
2. By using Reflection

My DLL

```
namespace MathHelper
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

My Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Using referenced dll in project
            Helper helper = new Helper();
            Console.WriteLine(helper.add(4,5));

            //Using Reflection
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\TestMathHelper\TestMathHelper\bin\Debug\MathHelper.dll");
            Type type = assembly.GetType("MathHelper.Helper");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("add");
            int result = (int)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {4, 5});
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Both results worked and displayed 9.

Which method should I prefer?
When should I use Reflection and when not?
What is the advantage of Reflection?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Use reflection only if other, simpler (and/or faster) approaches are not feasible. Always remember: Your goal should be to write readable, maintainable code. Ask and answer this yourself: Which of the two approaches you outlined in your question would result in better readable and better maintainable source code? (Btw, maintainability encompasses not only future extensions/modifications to source code, but also the ability/simplicity of debugging and troubleshooting code)

Comment: Which method was more convenient for you and has less code? Looks like it's the first - reference.

Answer (score 3):

If at all possible we want to write type-safe code where the compiler tells us whether or not we're calling a method that actually exists, whether we're passing the correct argument, etc. That way if something is wrong the code won't even compile, and we see the problem before we can even try to run our code.

Looking at the code with reflection, here are some things that could go wrong. In each case, if we used referenced assemblies and strongly-typed objects and methods, the compiler would catch this and warn us. Using reflection the code compiles but we don't find out about problems until we run the program:

```
        // The assembly might not be there. Or we can't load it.
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\TestMathHelper\TestMathHelper\bin\Debug\MathHelper.dll");  

        // The assembly doesn't have a type with that name.
        Type type = assembly.GetType("MathHelper.Helper");

        // The type doesn't have a constructor with no arguments.
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // The type doesn't have a method called "add".
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("add");

        // The "add" method doesn't take two ints as arguments or doesn't return an int.
        int result = (int)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {4, 5});
```

Not to mention that for us or the developer who comes next, being able to type a class name and have our IDE suggest the names of methods and properties is awesome. Otherwise we'd have to go look at the source code or documentation for the other class every time to see what its members are, what arguments it takes, what those arguments mean, and what it returns.

Reflection is usually better in cases where the specific type is both unknown and isn't as important.

For example, we could write a method that takes a `List<T>` where `T` is some object, and then it reads all the public properties of each instance and writes them all to a CSV file.

```
public void WriteToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, StreamWriter writer)
```

In that case we're not writing the method to handle a particular type. We don't really care what the type is. Whatever `T` is, we'd use reflection to find out what its public properties are. Then we'd use those properties to get the corresponding values for each item.

That's an over-generalization. There are many valid cases for using reflection. What we should avoid is using it when we're dealing with known types and there's a way to do what we want without reflection. If we paint ourselves into a corner and it looks like we need to use reflection then maybe we can fix part of the design. Or if we think we need reflection we can get another set of eyes on it. I only say this because while reflection is useful, it gets used in a lot of cases where it's unnecessary and makes code more fragile and harder to understand.